# Can I retrieve Arabic text that stored in varchar column in Arabic Collate that stored from another database in Latin Collate

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, varchar, collate

I have two database one of them in Latin collate and have Arabic data. In some case I take data that stored in the first database and store it in the second database table which has Arabic collate but each column in both database have `varchar` datatype. When I store data in the second database, It stored text with question mark.

If I change the type to `nvarchar` every thing goes well but old data still has question mark how can I retrieve the old data

I try to get old data but I get unreadable text with question mark.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.cust_supp (
    company_id t_id_char2   NOT NULL,
    acc_name_a t_id_var70       NULL,
    acc_name_e t_id_var70       NULL,
    closed_by  numeric(4,0)     NULL COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.dcl_item_update (

    item_update_id   numeric(18,0) NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    item_group_id    numeric(18,0) NOT NULL,
    change_column_id numeric(9,0)  NOT NULL,
    dcl_record_key   numeric(9,0)  NOT NULL,
    old_value        varchar(510)      NULL COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS,
    new_value        varchar(510)      NULL COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
);
```

I store the `acc_name_a` value in to the columns `old_value` and `new_value`.

Comment: _"but each column in both database have `varchar` datatype"_ - **oops**

Comment: Please post your **full** `CREATE TABLE` statements and the **exact** `COLLATE` names you're using.

Comment: _"I change the type to `nvarchar` every thing goes well but old data still has question mark how can I retrieve the old data"_ - restore a backup from before the column type change.

Comment: Which database system do you use? How **exactly** do you store the data=

Comment: I edited the question with create statement @Dai

Comment: why are you using `numeric` instead of `int` for what are clearly columns for integer values?

Comment: I cannot use a back up because it is a log table so the data may be changed @Dai

Comment: \*facepalm\* - I think you're SOL - or tell your boss you'll have to take the database offline to restore the deleted data. Also, consider using Temporal Tables instead of application-managed auditing tables.

Comment: I used sql server and store data using stored procedure I take the value from the first table and store it in other table  @NicoHaase

Comment: I use numeric because it is integrated with old system that use it as a numeric and I can not edit it @Dai

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

Did this work  ?
(I don't have an SQL Server right now to try, and I'm not sure if it's really what you want either...)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.dcl_item_update (old_value)
SELECT closed_by COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS as closed_by 
FROM dbo.cust_supp
```

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding of my question I insert to the table previously but because of the difference of collation I can not read the column old value it appears like 'E??? ??????¤ ??????? ????µ???' So I ask if there is anyway to read it

Comment: @haneen `SELECT old_value COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS as old_value FROM dbo.dcl_item_update ` this maybe ?